# Edge Unspecified Error With Angular 4 Forms

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

In an Angular 4.2.0 app, any page that has at least two input elements present cause Microsoft Edge to throw "Script 65535: Unspecified Error" (line 1, col 1 of the html) every second. No other unexpected behavior occurs, but I am worried that there may be a bug that I have not noticed.

The modules I am importing are BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, ReactiveFormsModule, and RouterModule. I've tried getting rid of FormsModule, the ReactiveFormsModule, and the RouterModule, but the same error is thrown.

I've also tried creating an empty angular2 app and adding two text fields to the default template with the version set to "^2.3.1"; the same error occurs.

This problem does not occur in Chrome 62.0.3202.94.

I'm on Edge 40.15063.674.0. Does anyone know why this error is being thrown, and/or if it is cause for concern?

Comment: have you included any polyfills?